# $ionicNavBarDelegate.getTitle() does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am using ionic framework and I have a search icon which is bind with a custom directive. It works like the search icon of Whatsapp, when you click it the view title is hidden and the search input text appears.

My problem is that the view title is not been hidden. I am using:

```
<ion-nav-title>{{viewTitle}}</ion-nav-title>
```

And two change the view title I am using:

```
title = $ionicNavBarDelegate.getTitle();
$ionicNavBarDelegate.setTitle('');
```

When I debug this point I can see that the title variable is undefined. Can anyone help me with this ?

View:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title>{{viewTitle}}</ion-nav-title>
  <search-bar ng-model="search"></search-bar>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Search Directive:

```
.directive('searchBar', [function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
},
require: ['^ionNavBar', '?ngModel'],
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
template: '<ion-nav-buttons side="right">'+
        '<div class="searchBar">'+
          '<div class="searchTxt" ng-show="ngModel.show">'+
              '<div class="bgdiv"></div>'+
              '<div class="bgtxt">'+
                '<input type="text" placeholder="Procurar..." ng-model="ngModel.txt">'+
              '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<i class="icon placeholder-icon" ng-click="ngModel.txt=\'\';ngModel.show=!ngModel.show"></i>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</ion-nav-buttons>',

compile: function (element, attrs) {
  var icon=attrs.icon
      || (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() && 'ion-android-search')
      || (ionic.Platform.isIOS()     && 'ion-ios7-search')
      || 'ion-search';
  angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.icon')).addClass(icon);

  return function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrls) {
    var navBarCtrl = ctrls[0];
    $scope.navElement = $attrs.side === 'right' ? navBarCtrl.rightButtonsElement : navBarCtrl.leftButtonsElement;

  };
},
controller: ['$scope','$ionicNavBarDelegate', function($scope,$ionicNavBarDelegate){
  var title, definedClass;
  $scope.$watch('ngModel.show', function(showing, oldVal, scope) {
    if(showing!==oldVal) {
      if(showing) {
        if(!definedClass) {
          var numicons=$scope.navElement.children().length;
          angular.element($scope.navElement[0].querySelector('.searchBar')).addClass('numicons'+numicons);
        }

        title = $ionicNavBarDelegate.getTitle();
        $ionicNavBarDelegate.setTitle('');
      } else {
        $ionicNavBarDelegate.setTitle(title);
      }
    } else if (!title) {
      title = $ionicNavBarDelegate.getTitle();
    }
  });
    }]
  };
}])
```